# Custom Object Inspector Components?

Tags: delphi

I have several forms in a project I am working on, each form contains their own different properties and value edits such as TEdits, TTrackBars and TSpinEdits etc. These forms work in a similar way to how a InputBox Dialog works where it displays the form, you enter a value and if the ModalResult is mrOk you handle the result accordingly.

I am now realising that this is not the most practical solution especially with several forms, and even more to add. I think the best GUI design option here would be something similar to the trusty Delphi Object Inspector on the Main form, it would also be easier to maintain.

What I don't need though is an Object Inspector that displays properties from a component class, but instead I want to populate the Object Inspector with my own fields and types.

So far the only component I have found that comes close is the Berg NextInspector found here: http://www.bergsoft.net/component/next-inspector/overview.htm which allows filling the Object Inspector with your own data:

[image]

I would like to see the alternatives before considering purchasing the above so I can weigh up my other options and compare the pros and cons between different component libraries.

So far I have not found anything that works like this one, most just seem to mimic the Delphi Object Inspector which is not what I want.

Is there any other Object Inspector components similar to the Berg Next Inspector to allow custom fields and types?

Comment: Go ahead and get this component. Do they have a demo? If not, looks cheap enough to try.

Comment: They do have a demo and it works great.

Comment: hum it's strange : i'm also interested by their components, but should i go [bergsoftware.net](http://www.bergsoftware.net) or [bergsoft.net](http://www.bergsoft.net/) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do with [Virtual Treeview](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview)

Comment: Have not used Virtual Treeview before, but if it works it will save me $69 which is the cost of Next Inspector :)

Comment: @Blobby Virtual TreeView is the best bang for the buck and very flexible, there are worst components out there that costs money...

Comment: @Blobby, to be more specific, in Advanced demo, unit [`PropertiesUnit.pas`](http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/source/browse/trunk/Demos/Advanced/PropertiesDemo.pas). Anyway VirtualTreeView is wonderful component and now I can't imagine live without it! I left using of standard components like *TListBox*, *TListView*, *TTreeView*...

Comment: $69 for the component in the question looks like wonderful value to me

Comment: @DavidHeffernan much cheaper then the DevExpress ones at over $179.

Comment: I think I will experiment with the Virtual Treeview component and see if I can fit it into my needs, if not then it looks like the Berg Next Inspector component is the best bought option.

Comment: @Blobby, playing with the demo from your screenshot have to say it will take some time with VT, but it's not impossible. If you decide for one or the other, VirtualTreeView is well written open source component and it's good at least to try.

Comment: @TLama the screenshot looks more complex than what I actually will be trying, I just needed some basic custom property editors. If I get stuck I will ask :)

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera my application is not commercial, more a personal project. I just know from a design point of view it would be better for my needs to have an Inspector control like that one implemented now rather than later whether it is released as commercial or not.

Comment: @Blobby - when something is not related to the problem I'm solving then I just try to avoid thinking about it. If you don't want to waste time on this, just go ahead and buy it. From their compiled demo it looks like Berg components are quite good.

Comment: Looks like the URL has changed to http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used it myself yet, but I think [DevExpress's ExpressVerticalGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExVerticalGrid/) should meet your criteria.

[image]

(The samples are a *little* bit colorful for my taste but you aren't forced to use background bitmaps all over. :-))

Comment: Looks good and I know support is likely to be equally as good but the price is over $179.

Comment: I love DevExpress grids but they won't save you much work compared to a VirtualTreeView.

Answer (score 3):

There is also TJvInspector from [JEDI Visual Component Library](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/)

Comment: If I can I try and avoid the Jedi libraries.

Comment: +1 for "If I can I try and avoid the Jedi libraries" - now, if they were documented, it would be different matter